# why is circular progress bar not filling with timing?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

HTML

```
      <canvas id="circle" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

JS

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById('circle').getContext('2d');
  ctx.lineWidth = 10 ;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F' ;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#09F' ;

  var totalTime = 60 ;
  var start = 0 ;

  function bharJa() {
  let endAngle = (start/totalTime*360)-90 ;
  ctx.beginPath() ;
  ctx.arc(75,75,60,270*(Math.PI/180),endAngle*(Math.PI/180));
  ctx.stroke() ;
  start++ ;
      if(start > totalTime){
            clearInterval(intervalId)  ;
      }
  }

  var intervalId = window.setInterval(bharJa,1000);
```

this should be work like when every second pass ,circle should complete with that second.for example my total time is 60 second & it start with 0 than after 1 minute circle will be complete. but when i run this circle already present there.

Comment: What did you expect `270*(Math.PI/180)` would produce? If you want to make it start at 12 oclock, it should be `-90*(Math.PI/180)` (or `-Math.PI/2`).  Also don't forget to clear your canvas at each frame. https://jsfiddle.net/h56t8co1/1

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m4xspwa/)

Comment: okay i get it but i was trying starting from 270 to ending 270 .

Comment: Won't ask why since it will produce the same result but less readable, but then you need to add 270 to your endAngle, not substract 90, so that it makes a full turn. https://jsfiddle.net/h56t8co1/2/. Ah or you wanted it to do the inverse, i.e emptying instead of filling? Then you need the [anticlockwise flag to be set](https://jsfiddle.net/h56t8co1/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clockwise direction

The function `ctx.arc` creates a path that is drawn clockwise, if the last argument is not true.

You are drawing from 270 to -90 which it can not do in a clockwise direction so the function draws a complete circle.

To draw part of a circle the second angle should be greater than the first angle and less than 360deg from the first angle, if you are drawing in a clockwise direction.

So rather than set the end angle, use the time to just set the angle distance and add that to the start angle.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('circle').getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#09F';

const totalTime = 60;
const startAngle = 270
var start = 0;
ctx.lineCap = "round";

function bharJa() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
  const angleDist = (start / totalTime * 360);
  ctx.lineWidth = 16;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#07D';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 60, startAngle * (Math.PI / 180), (startAngle + angleDist ) * (Math.PI / 180));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.lineWidth = 12;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.stroke();
  start++;
  if (start > totalTime) { start = 0 }

}

var intervalId = window.setInterval(bharJa, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="circle" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
Time * 10
```